# Why do some sentinel loops require break to terminate? c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop, sentinel

I have a loop that looks something like this

```
int temp = 0; 
int menuItem;
while (temp != -1 && temp < 5)
{
    cout << "Order " << temp + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> menuItem;
    arrayData[temp] = menuItem;
    temp++;
    break;
}
```

When I learned to use sentinels, I did not learn them using break...
for example.

```
int total = 0;
int points;
int game = 1; 

cout << "Enter the points for game #" << game << endl;
cin >> points;

while (points !=-1)
{
    total += points;

    game++;
    cout << "Enter the points for game #" << game << endl;
    cin >> points;
}
```

This second loop continues on towards infinity until the value -1 is entered, and then it stops without the need for a `break;`. My first loop however will not stop when the sentinel value is entered unless the break is included.

Why is that?

Comment: Your first loop exits based on `temp` but your input is `menuItem`. Therefore, input of `-1` does nothing

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you're asking. When you stepped through the code, how did it differ each time?  Loops just check the condition each time, so you must be changing the values tested in the condition

Comment: under what condition do you expect that loop to terminate? It will keep going till temp == 5

Answer (score 2):

While statement always repeat until the set condition get to false. In your first code example

```
while (temp != -1 && temp < 5)
```

Here, the while loop will exit if `temp` is `-1` or `temp` is equal to `5`. But, you insert `break` in your code which is will stop or force your `while loop` condition to stop.

```
while (condition) {
    // Some code.

    // Even if the condition true, it will stop because of break.
    break;
}
```

In your second code, the condition set to

```
while (points !=-1)
```

so the `while` will only stop or exit, if the `points` variable has value of `-1`.

After understand the basic, you will find the answer for your question on why on the first `while` it didn't stop if there is no `break;`. The answer is because the condition on that `while` is still true so that the `while` execute again.

Answer (score 1):

`break` always breaks the loop when it´s called.

In your first loop, however, you´re reading `menuItem`, no `temp`.

So, if you in enter -1 `menuItem` equals -1, no `temp`.

Comment: I still don't see then why it runs in the first place. Wouldn't it break after the first iteration of the loop? This loop will run 1-5 times, but only breaks when the sentinel value is entered.

Comment: Ok, it runs in first place because temp = 0, so is temp != -1 ? true.             Is temp < 5 ? true. So the condition evaluates to true and the first cicle of the 'while' is executed. Then the program sees instruction 'break' at the end of the cicle, so it gets out of the loop with just the first cicle, no more.